# RemoveHandlers in the derived class

Tags: .net, vb.net, event-handling

I use to set `WithEvents` variables to `Nothing` in `Destuctor`, because this will "Remove" all the Handlers associated with `Handles` keyword. Will this have the same effect for derivated classes?

```
Class A
    Protected WithEvents _Foo as Button

    Private Sub _Foo_Click Handles _Foo.Click
        ' ... some Click action '
    End Sub

    Public Sub Dispose(disposing as Boolean)
        If disposing then _Foo = Nothing ' remove handler _Foo_Click '
    End Sub
End Class

Class B
    Inherits A

    Private Sub _Foo_Move Handles _Foo.Move
        ' ... some Move action '
    End Sub

    ' ????? will or NOT remove OR handler _Foo_Move the base Dispose??'
    Public Overrides Sub Dispose(disposing as Boolean)           
        'If disposing then _Foo = Nothing '
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Sub
End Class
```

**PS.** For more clarity, suppose that `_Foo` button comes from exterior and lives more that the `A` class.

Comment: +1 for observing the importance of unwiring events in Dispose.  Minor nit, though: declaring a WithEvents thing "foo" creates a property named "foo" and a field named "_foo".  Calling the thing "_foo" means the field will be "__foo", but the property name "_foo" will look like a backing-field name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The `_Foo = Nothing` statement in the derivated class will change the base class' protected local `_Foo` to nothing, thus removing all event handlers.